# Cache with expiring keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, web-scraping, mashup

I'm working on a mashup site and would like to limit the number of fetches to scrape the source sites.  There is essentially one bit of data I need, an integer, and would like to cache it with a defined expiration period.

To clarify, I only want to cache the integer, not the entire page source.

Is there a ruby or rails feature or gem that already accomplishes this for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is `ActiveSupport::Cache::Store`

> An abstract cache store class. There are multiple cache store
>   implementations, each having its own additional features. See the
>   classes under the ActiveSupport::Cache module, e.g.
>   ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore. MemCacheStore is currently the
>   most popular cache store for large production websites.
>
> Some implementations may not support all methods beyond the basic
>   cache methods of fetch, write, read, exist?, and delete.
>
> ActiveSupport::Cache::Store can store any serializable Ruby object.
>
> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html

```
cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new
cache.read('Chicago')   # => nil 
cache.write('Chicago', 2707000)
cache.read('Chicago')   # => 2707000
```

Regarding the expiration time, this can be done by passing the time as a initialization parameter

```
cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new(expires_in: 5.minutes)
```

If you want to cache a value with a different expiration time, you can also set this when writing a value to the cache

```
cache.write(key, value, expires_in: 1.minute) # Set a lower value for one entry
```

Answer (score 3):

See [Caching with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-store), particularly the `:expires_in` option to [`ActiveSupport::Cache::Store`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html).

For example, you might go:

```
value = Rails.cache.fetch('key', expires_in: 1.hour) do
    expensive_operation_to_compute_value()
end
```